# diff de um arquivo em um commit específico e HEAD

Tags: git, diff

Como posso comparar a diferença ao `HEAD` e o último commit que contenha arquivo em específico?

Para achar o útlimo commit que contenha o arquivo li as informações em [git diff file against its last change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412252/2083705)
.
Porém ao executar o comando `git diff HEAD 7de795700d64093afcbd79af03ea4fcfc3ec25b2  src/rodain_get_directions/nodes/retrieve_content.py` no terminal não é retornado nada.

Me baseei no link abaixo para fazer o diff:
[How do I diff the same file between two different commits on the same branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/how-do-i-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch?rq=1)

Comment: Faltou o `--`, não? `git diff HEAD 7de795700d64093afcbd79af03ea4fcfc3ec25b2 --  src/rodain_get_directions/nodes/retrieve_content.py`

Answer (score -4):

`$ git diff`

> git-diff - Exibe as mudanças entre os commits, o commit, a árvore de trabalho, etc
> fonte: [Git -fit-diff Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/pt_BR)

Para verificarmos as diferenças entre arquivos alterados e comitados, poderemos usar o seguinte comando: `$ git diff`,serão mostradas apenas as mudanças feitas.

> O git diff não poderá ser utilizado para arquivos novos, que ainda
> não estão sendo rastreados pelo Git (ou seja, que ainda não tiveram o
> primeiro git add executado).fonte:[Controlando versões com Git e GitHub - Casa do Codigo.pdf](https://github.com/free-educa/books/blob/main/books/Controlando%20vers%C3%B5es%20com%20Git%20e%20GitHub%20-%20Casa%20do%20Codigo.pdf)

Verificação de mudanças rastreadas `$ git diff --staged`

Através do seguinte comendo `$ git log -n 1 --oneline` podemos mostrar podemos mostrar o último commit.
Em posse do último commite e executando o comando `$ git diff <último commit>` poderemos ver as alterações rastreadas e não rastreadas. Teremos a mesma saída com `$ git diff HEAD`.

> `$ git diff [<opções>] <commit> [--] [<caminho>…​]`
> Este formulário exibe as modificações feitas por você na sua árvore de trabalho relativo ao nome do . É possível utilizar o HEAD para compará-lo com o commit mais recente ou para comparar com o cume de um ramo diferente.

Verificando diferença entre dois comites.

> `$ git diff [<opções>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<caminho>…​]`
> Isso é para exibir as alterações entre os dois  arbitrários.
> fonte: [Git -fit-diff Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/pt_BR)

Podemos usar `$ git diff <últimos commit>~2`

Para sanar mais dúvidas indico o seguinte tutorial.
[git tutorial Series' Articles](https://dev.to/danielle8farias/series/5484)

Comment: Tá, mas a pergunta é como comparar o HEAD com o último commit contendo um arquivo em especifico.

Comment: com `$ git log --oneline` você terá um resumo dos seus comites, com o comando
 `$ git diff <commit>..<commit>` você verá as modificações e se você adicionar o `--stat` ao comando, ficando asssim `$git diff --stat <commit>..<commit>`, será apresentado um resumo das modificações